# How to load and show jpeg using Rserve in Java(Eclipse)?

Tags: rserve, loadimage

I'd like to rotate a jpeg in Eclipse using Rserve(). The code in R is like this.

```
install.packages("jpeg")
install.packages("Rserve")
library(Rserve)
library(jpeg)
library(grid)
setwd("I:/rr1")
aa<-readJPEG("bird.jpg")
r<-t(aa[,,1])
g<-t(aa[,,2])
b<-t(aa[,,3])
col <- rgb(r,g,b)
dim(col) <- dim(r)
grid.raster(col, interpolate=FALSE)
```

In Eclipse, I don't know how to use the Rserve() to fulfill the same task. 
Initially I use

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(new File("i:\\rr1\\bird.jpg"));
```

and then

```
c.eval("aa<-image");
```

But it doesn't work.
What's more, it seems that I cannot use

```
c.eval("grid.raster(col, interpolate=FALSE)");
```

in Rserve() to merge 3 channels into one image finally.
Does anyone know how to do it??
Thanks!!

Comment: This has really nothing to do with Rserve -- what device are you using? I would recommend an image device if you are looking into raster operations, e.g., `Cairo` supports in-memory raster operations if that's what you want.

Comment: @SimonUrbanek I just installed r and Eclipse in one single computer, I don't know whether Cairo can transfer image to matrix since I supposed to do sth from the matrix later.

Answer (score 0):

Calling image rendering functions from Rserve isn't that much supported because render functions work best from the R GUI (where the display window to render the image has been specified, defined and properly formatted).

You might want to try to write the raster generated to a file and then read the file from Java using ImageIO.read().